# Header/Content/Footer divs inside a particular div?

Tags: html, css

I feel this is kind of a very basic question but I cannot figure out a good solution

How can I have a

- header: always on top
- footer: always on bottom
- content: right below header. it should start right after header and if there is too much content its should be scrollable.

within a particular div? not the entire screen

I was trying with flex box and works fine when there is a lot of contents in the `content` but when there is only a few of content in `content` is centered :( .I want it to be top aligned.

Here is what I have done so far:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/nacho4d/ddv7ytkf/1/

html:

```
<div id="main">
    <div style="background-color:lightblue;" class="header">Header - height is variable but just a couple of lines at maximum. Should not overflow</div>
    <div style="background-color:khaki;" class="content">
        <div>
          Content - height is variable. There could be a lot of content here so its overflow should be auto.<br/>
          "Lorem ipsum ... Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? "
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:pink;" class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#main {
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;

    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;

    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;

    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.header {
}
.content {
    overflow:auto
}
.footer {
}
```

**ANSWER:**

Basically the same as @Abhitalks answer, I just added webkit vendor prefixes: http://fiddle.jshell.net/nacho4d/ddv7ytkf/11/ It works great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `flex` rule on the children.

```
.header {
    flex: 0 0 auto; /* do not grow or shrink, keep the flex basis auto */
}
.content {
    flex: 1 1 auto; /* grow or shrink as appropriate */
    overflow:auto
}
.footer {
    flex: 0 0 auto; /* do not grow or shrink, keep the flex basis auto */
}
```

Fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ddv7ytkf/5/

Comment: I have been reading about flex-basis but still don't get it. How it works? What does it mean really?

Comment: @nacho4d: Flex allows for elements to grow or shrink as required to fill the available space. `flex-basis` specifies what width/height should be used as a *basis* of growing or shrinking the flexed element. You can see it as a starting dimension. For example, if you give a `flex-basis` of `100px` and `flex-grow` as `1`; then the element will start out at `100px` and will grow by a factor of 1 as compared to other siblings.

Answer (score 1):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/ddv7ytkf/8/

Is this what you meant? (see fiddle)
Paste more text into the content field and it should scroll if it is bigger than the arbitrary main height that you set.

CSS

```
 #main {
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display: block;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.wrapper {    
    height: 150px; 
}
.header {
    top: 0;
    height: auto;
}
.content {
    position:relative;
    overflow:visible;
}
.footer {
    bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div style="background-color:lightblue;" class="header">Header - height is variable but just a couple of lines at maximum. Should not overflow</div>
        <div style="background-color:khaki;" class="content">
        <p>Content - height is variable. There could be a lot of content here so its overflow should be Content - height is variable. There could be a lot of content here so its overflow should be Content - height is variable. There could be a lot of content here so its overflow should be Content - height is variable. There could be a lot of content here so its overflow should be Content - height is variable. There could be a lot of content here so its overflow should be</p>
    </div>
        <div style="background-color:pink;" class="footer">Footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I also made a version of the Abhitalks with a visible header and footer but scrollable content 
https://jsfiddle.net/ddv7ytkf/9/

Answer (score 1):

`.content { flex-grow: 1; }` should get you the result you're after, but the preferred method is to instead use the `flex` property, which takes three parameters that are shorthand for `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `flex-basis` (in that order).

The second and third are optional, though, so if you set only one parameter (`flex: 1;`) it's the same as writing `flex-grow: 1;`

The default is `flex: 0 1 auto;`, so writing `flex: 1;` gives you the same result (in this case) as `flex: 1 1 auto;`. But what's odd about the behavior of `flex` is that while both `flex: 1;` and `flex: 1 1 auto;` give you the same result, `flex: auto;` and `flex: auto 1 auto;` don't (incidentally, `flex: auto;` will also get you the result you're after, `flex: auto 1 auto;` won't). This is because of the way that `flex` "intelligently" sets the other two values, so beware of unexpected results when you're using this shorthand.

So `.content { flex: 1; }` or `.content { flex: auto; }` should do the trick, just be mindful of how those values might vary once you change `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis`.